# How can I finish this stateQuiz.java program

Tags: java, arrays, loops

I want to ask the user questions on different states using arrays, but it outputs exception in thread "main" when I compile it.

```
import java.util.*;

class StateQuiz{

    public static void main( String[] args ){
        boolean[] asked = new boolean[10];
        boolean correct[] = new boolean[10];
        Arrays.fill(asked, true);
        String [] answers={"Alaska","Ohio","Illinois","Ohio","Florida","Hawaii","New York","California","Maryland","Texas"};
        String [] questions={"What is the largest state?","Where is the city of Columbus located?","Where is the city of Springfield located?","Where is Ohio State located?","What is the orange state?","What is the most southern state?","Where is the Big Apple?","Where is Hollywood?","What state is Baltimore located?","What state looks like a boot?"};
         int nextQ = -1;
         boolean good = false;
         do {
            nextQ = getNextQuestion(asked);
            good = quizUser(answers,questions,nextQ);
            asked[nextQ] = true;
            if (good == true) {
                correct[nextQ] = true;
            } else {
                correct[nextQ] = false;
            }
         } while (nextQ != -1);

         printResults(correct);
    }

    public static int getNextQuestion(boolean[] questions_asked){
        int[] poo = {};
        for (int i = 0; i < questions_asked.length; i ++) {
            if (questions_asked[i] == false) {
                poo[poo.length] = i;
            }
        }

        if (poo.length == 0) {
            return -1;
        }

        int rand = (int) Math.round(Math.random() * poo.length);
        return poo[rand];
    }

    public static boolean quizUser(String[]answers,String[]questions, int nextQ)
    {
        System.out.println(questions[nextQ]);
        String an;
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner( System.in );
        an = keyboard.nextLine();
        if(an.equalsIgnoreCase(answers[nextQ])){
            System.out.println("Correct");
            return true;
        }else{
            System.out.println("Incorrect");
            return false;
        }
    }


    //finding the average correct answers
    public static void printResults (boolean[] questions){
        int correctQuestions = 0;
        double average = 0;
        for(int i=0; i < questions.length ; i++) {
            if (questions[i]) {
                correctQuestions += 1;
            }
        }

        average = correctQuestions / questions.length;

        //return average;
        System.out.println("Your average socre is:" + average);

        if (average > 80)   {
            System.out.println ("Wow! You really know a lot about state birds!");
        } else if (average > 40 && average < 80 )   {
            System.out.println ("Apparently you know some state birds.");
        } else if (average < 40)    {
            System.out.println ("You could spruce up your knowledge on state birds.");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with this line:

> int nextQ = -1;

At line 15 it'll be:

> good = quizUser(answers,questions,-1);

And, Line 48 in your code will be:

> System.out.println(questions[-1]);

Therefore, you'll be getting ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException because you're trying to access -1th element in an array.

Remember that in case of do-while loops, it first executes and then checks for the condition specified in "while". Changing it to a simple while statement might be the easiest solution if do-while is confusing for you.